# Running seatunnel CDC job using flink on different Server

Tags: apache-flink, cdc

I have configured Seatunnel on one instance, which we'll refer to as instance-1. Additionally, I have set up Flink on a separate instance, known as instance-2. Now, I would like to run a Seatunnel CDC job on instance-1 using Flink on instance-2. I would like to know if Seatunnel supports this setup and, if it does, how to configure Flink in seatunnel.